# Unity 2D box collider to call and run C# script

Tags: c#, triggers, unity-game-engine

I have a camera shake C# script that I want to run once the player triggers a box collider?
The camera shake code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraShake : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform camTransform;

    public float shake = 0f;

    public float shakeAmount = 0.7f;

    Vector3 originalPos;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (camTransform == null)
        {
            camTransform = GetComponent(typeof(Transform)) as Transform;
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        originalPos = camTransform.localPosition;
    }

    void Update()
}
```

Comment: Did you attach the script to the gameObject having the collider?

Comment: Yeah, and it wouldn't activate?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you did not add the `OnTriggerEnter`, `OnTriggerStay` or `OnTriggerExit` ( depending of what you want to achieve ) function to the script.

For e.g:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
  if(other.tag == "Player"){
    // shake the camera here..
  }
}
```

Don't forget to check the `trigger` box in the box collider.